# Beautifulsoup gets a different content than actual text

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

As the title says; the content that i'm getting is different than the actual content on the page. I'm trying to get a "href" info and a text inside of "p" tag(class=center-block) from a certain group of tags. When try to get "href" attribute from a link(second link below), it returns "/Login" text instead of what's inside of href attribute. And similarly when i try get the inner text of a "p" tag, it returns "Company Name" text. So it completely returns different values than actual contents. I could reach most of others but couldn't get the actual contents of these two elements specifically, even though i could see the actual contents when i inspect the elements in browsers.

Python code:

```py
r = requests.get('https://www.examplesite.com/winners', headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

list_of_winners = [item for item in soup.find_all('div', class_='bottom')]
list_of_winners.remove(list_of_winners[0]) # 0 indexed element is none, remove it from the list.

    index_counter = 0    # index counter for dictionaries
    for i in list_of_winners:

        ## Get the link 
        self.contest_link[index_counter] = i.find('a')['href']

        ## Get the title
        self.contest_title[index_counter] = i.find('p', class_='center-block').text.strip()

        index_counter += 1
    index_counter = 0   # Reset the index counter
```

The html code:

```
<div class="bottom">
  <div class="likes_count">
    <a href="javascript:void()" style="color: #333;" class="contest-like-unlike" data-type="like" data-contest-id="24454">
        <i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i>
    </a>
    <span class="popover_win">9 Likes</span>
  </div>
  <a style="float: right" href="https://www.example.com/retail-business/retail-business-24604">
   <p class="center-block">Retail Business</p>
  </a><span>&nbsp;</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is the rest of the [mcve].?

Comment: Seems like the content you are trying to retrieve is loaded by javascript?

Comment: @wwii I didn't think sharing the whole html code is necessary since there isn't too much to see. This is pretty much it. Another reason is that i thought it might be because of some other reason more than directly html tag problem.

Comment: … I see the data but I don't see what you are using to extract the interesting parts, that is what is missing from the [mcve] - the minimal code to extract the text from the markup in your example. `The code: ` - you posted data not code.

Comment: @cylee That's what i was suspicious of. Is there another way to get the actual content you think?

Comment: @wwii Sorry i should have shared the python code in the first place. I guess i was expecting people to give more like theoretical answers. Since standartly there doesn't seem any problem for python side or server side to cause a problem. Because i have done web scraping more than once and this is first time i'm getting this kind of error.